# What does the type parameter <T> in the method definition mean?

Tags: java

```
public class GenericMethods {
    public <T> void f(T x) {
        System.out.println(x.getClass().getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMethods gm = new GenericMethods();
        gm.f("");
        gm.f(1);
        gm.f(1.0);
        gm.f(1.0F);
        gm.f('c');
        gm.f(gm);
    }
}
/* Output:  
java.lang.String  
java.lang.Integer  
java.lang.Double  
java.lang.Float  
java.lang.Character  
GenericMethods  */
```

What does `public <T> void f(T x)`  mean? Is it a return type?
But the function doesn't actually return anything. What does it refer to? I couldn't place it under any of the general function header categories : like acces-specifier, return-type,etc.

Comment: It's a generic type parameter, declaring that the method is generic, that's all. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a generic type parameter. See [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) about *Generics*.